# Monitor WCF Service via WPF app

Tags: wcf, monitor

I am designing a WCF service that will serve clients that request things like 'GetProduct' and 'UpdateProduct'. In addition, there will be another service that the clients will subscribe to that will send them PUSH notifications.

The 'PULL' and 'PUSH' WCF services will run under a Windows service.

I would like to encapsulate some sort of monitoring solution that allows me to open a WPF application that will connect to the services and show me how many clients are connected right now to both services (supposed to be identical) and will allow me to disconnect clients from the service and maybe view logs that the service has logged.

How do I design this on the services side ?

Do I need to create a 3rd service for the 'monitoring' app that when requested - will check how many clients are connected to the 'PULL' and 'PUSH' services ?

Or do I just add a function 'GetNumOfClients' and 'DisconnectClient' to the 'PUSH' and 'PULL' services ? this seems wrong, because it introduces logic to these services that does not belong there, and also allows clients to disconnect each other...

Answer (score 1):

For logging use log4net or [health monitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649765.aspx). Log4net is versatile and configurable. You can turn on [WCF diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731055.aspx) logging which has extensive information about what is going on with your service on  You can read here how to turn on and use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735120.aspx) providers to instrument your service and what performance [counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx) are available.

Why is there a requirement for disconnecting a client? You can "disconnect" the client when you throw an exception in your method which fault's the client channel but beyond that you should not be concerned with managing service connections.

Comment: There is a requirement for an administrator to be able to remotely disconnect a client.

Comment: How the administrator determine which client to disconnect?

Comment: The administrator will run a WPF app that connects to this 'monitoring' service that will tell it which clients are connected to the services, and the administrator will be able to disconnect any of them, or request a log of what exactly they did in the system